# Access asset from asset-pipeline in gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, assets

I have a rails application which uses the asset-pipeline. Loading an asset works fine, for example with `url_to_image`.

I have now a `gem` I want to have access to the asset-pipeline of the used rails application. So when using `url_to_image` in the gem, the same path should be created as when calling this directly from the rails application.

This is currently not the case. When calling this directly from the rails app, I get for e.g. `root/assets/my_asset.png`. When doing the same call from the gem, I get `root/images/my_asset.png`.

It seems somehow, the gem cannot access the app's asset-pipeline and therefore can't find it. For this, it falls back to `images` for the mounting directory.

What would be a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

A Gem does not know the assets of the application in which is included, otherwise it would have to know all the assets of all the applications in which it is included and this is not possibile.

There is probably something wrong in your project structure...what you can do is eventually put a default asset in the gem and change it in your application overriding it.

Comment: The rails app, as well as the gem are needing the same assets. When adding the assets to the gem, are they available in the app?

Comment: But how can I access an asset within the gem when serving the assets through the gem? My gem contains no a Rails::Engine, and serves the assets to the app.